# How to print React App component to PDF with Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, puppeteer, pdf-generation

I have to implement the following scenario in my React App:

1. Some not authorized user follows the page called "Request Program report"
2. They sends a request
3. Admin approves a request
4. User receives email with attached PDF file (contains report).

My approach is:

1. React App sends a request to the server
2. Server will handle if the request is approved by the admin
3. Server will call the endpoint launched on the Puppeteer container with simple Axios GET request.
4. Puppeteer will open new headless browser window with received React App url
5. PDF buffer returns to the server and send by the nodemailer.

Everything works fine when I pass e.g https://google.com. PDF is generated correctly. But empty PDF is returned for React App url. I have no idea there is a problem :(

**NestJS server code**:

```
await axios
  .get(`${PUPPETEER_APP_URL}/pdf`, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    params: { url: programUrl }
  })
```

**Puppeteer application code**:

Router:

```
app.get('/pdf', async (req, res) => {
  const url = req.query.url
  const result = await generatePdf(`${CLOUD_APP_URL}/${url}`)
  res.contentType('application/pdf');
  res.send(result);
});
```

Service:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const generatePdf = async (payload) => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
    });
  
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(payload, {
      waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0', 'load']
    })
    await page.emulateMediaType('screen')
    const pdf = await page.pdf();
    await browser.close();
  
    return pdf;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('GENERATE PDF ERROR :>> ', error);
  }
};

module.exports = generatePdf;
```

Response data looks like `data: <Buffer >`

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

```
 const downloadAsPDF = async ({ documentId }) => {
        let pdf = await fetch(url,{
            endpoint: `services/pdf?documentId=${documentId}`,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
            }
        });
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(pdf);
        link.download = `your-file-name.pdf`;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    };
```